# Is it possible display a graphic for 10ms on 10ms refresh rate monitor

Tags: graphics

You can get 10ms monitors. is there a way to display a graphic for 10ms such that it is in synch with the monitor. So the graphic will displayed for only one refresh. At the moment i am not worried about the technology, or language just fiddling with an idea that requires this.
Cheers

Comment: Yes, that's very easy. Most graphics APIs have a way to wait for v-sync, for instance. If you would have immersed yourself in actual graphics APIs first (e.g. a simple tutorial on OpenGL, no matter how outdated), you would have been exposed to these concepts almost immediately.

Comment: I love your tone :). Notice the difference in language, fiddle vs immerse. Thanks none the less